# Programmatically navigating a tab bar controller view returns incorrect child vc

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view controller (LayoutController2) as a child of a tab view controller . A ViewController (Scrollview) is instantiated from this LayoutController2 via segue when a button is clicked.

The Scrollview is not a child of the tab view controller.

My problem is when I try to navigate back to the LayoutController2 from the Scrollview via segue, I can get manage to navigate to every other child vc of tabbed view except the LayoutController2!

LayoutController2 is at index[1] of tab controller.viewControllers array.

```
if (segue.identifier == "segueBackToImages2"){

            // Get the tab bar controller

            var tabBarC : UITabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController;


            // index 1 of tab bar heirachy = LayoutController2

            var destionationView : LayoutController2 = tabBarC.viewControllers![1] as LayoutController2;

            println(tabBarC.viewControllers![1]);
```

Printing tabBarC.viewControllers![1] to log gives :

```
<LabMaternalhaematology.LayoutController2: 0x7b93e4f0>
```

If I iterate thought the child vac's of tab bar controller :

> Tabbar voews:  Total Views
>   Optional(5)) 
>   Tabbar voews:  Total Views Optional(5)) 
>   Tabbar voews:  Total Views Optional(5))
>   Tabbar voews:  Total
>   Views Optional(5)) 
>   Tabbar voews:  Total Views Optional(5))

But when the view instantiates it is never the LayoutController2, no matter what index I use it will always be another vc child of the tab cont just never the LayoUtConbtroller2.

Any input much appreciated.

Comment: A couple of things. ScrollView may not be a child, but it still is in the tab bar controller's hierarchy (a grandchild perhaps). Secondly, you don't go backwards to a previous controller with a segue unless you use an unwind -- that doesn't actually go back, it create a new instance of the tab bar controller.

Comment: Perfect unwind worked great. Out of interest, does viewDidLoad of the vc get called when we unwind back to it?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because you're going back to the same instance. ViewDidLoad is only executed once in the lifetime of a controller.

Comment: Ok so the instance is just taken from the stack?

Comment: Well, there is no stack really. The tab bar controller is the window's root view controller (I assume). If you're going to use an unwind, it should be from ScrollView to LayoutController2, not the tab bar controller (since there is no forward segue from the tab bar controller).

Comment: Ok cheers for the help